# I can't get the onsubmit button to post the warning in the <p> at the bottom of the form

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

```
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<title>Form</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function isValidUsername() {
    var user_name = document.getElementById("user_name");
    var pattern =/^[A-Za-z0-9]{8,15}/g;
    var patternreq_1 = /[A-Z]/g;
    var patternreq_2 = /[0-9]/g;

    if (pattern.test(user_name)){
        document.getElementById("error_message").innertext ="";
        return true;
    }

    else if (patternreq_1.test(user_name)==false && patternreq_2.test(user_name)==false){
            document.getElementById("error_message").innerText = 
                "*Please include a capitalized letter and a number in your user name.";
            return false;
    }
    else if (patternreq_1.test(user_name)==false && patternreq_2.test(user_name)==true){
            document.getElementById("error_message").innerText = 
                "*Please include a capitalized letter in your username.";
            return false;
    }
    else if (patternreq_1.test(user_name)==true && patternreq_2.test(user_name)==false){
            document.getElementById("error_message").innerText =
                "*Please include a number in your username.";
                return false;
    }
    else if (user_name.length<8){
            document.getElementById("error_message").innerText =
                "*Please include at least eight letters in your username.";
                return false;
    }

}
 </script>
</head>


<body>

<form  method="post" name="contact_form"  onSubmit="return isValidUsername()">
    <h1>Please Enter Your Name</h1>
    <p>Your Name: <input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit"></p>
    <p id="error_message" value="Use InnerText">&nbsp;</p>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

when i click submit now, it does not match the pattern, but rather cycles through the else if statements although it never comes up with "please include a capitalized letter" but only the other two. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You don't actually have a question in there, so I'll just take a guess at it

Comment: You also need to clear the error message if the user enters something good; and maybe make those else-ifs to prevent later errors from overwriting earlier errors. Overall, I'd suggest a little refactoring to clean things up a bit and possibly help you restructure things to be simpler.

Answer (score 2):

All of these:

```
if (user_name != pattern){ ...
```

Should be more [like this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html):

```
if (pattern.test(user_name)){ ...
```

Comment: plus what floatless said... I'd suggest investing in a good browser debugger. It will save you hours of headache. If you use Chrome, hit `ctrl-shift-i`; if you use Firefox, get the firebug extension; if you use IE8, hit `F12`

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong:

```
document.getElementById(error_message)
```

You should add single or double quotes to the argument:

```
document.getElementById("error_message")
```